# How to add animation json files in an arraylist & display those animations on the screen when we iterate?

Tags: json, kotlin, arraylist, android-animation, lottie

I have animation json file in the raw folder in res directory. I have made a data model , in which I want to store many properties with different data types.

Data Model

```
class ExerciseModel (
private var id:Int,
private var name:String,
private var isCompleted:Boolean,
private var isSelected:Boolean,
private var animationJson:String)
```

And then, I want to make an object of this class & store it in an ArrayList. as,

```
object Constants {

    fun defaultExerciseList():ArrayList<ExerciseModel>{
        val exerciseList=ArrayList<ExerciseModel>()
        val squat =ExerciseModel(1,"Squat",false,false, R.raw.squat.json)
        exerciseList.add(squat)
```

I have added the view in the activity_main.xml but it is not working.

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/exerciseAnimation"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_fileName="jumping_jack.json"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_speed="1" />
```

How to add the animation json file in the arraylist & make it display on the screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update model code:-

```
class ExerciseModel(
var id: Int,
var name: String,
var isCompleted: Boolean,
var isSelected: Boolean,
var animationJson: Int)
```

Add data in array:-

```
val exerciseList=ArrayList<ExerciseModel>()
    val squat = ExerciseModel(1,"Squat",false,false, R.raw.squat)
    exerciseList.add(squat)
    val load = ExerciseModel(2,"Load",false,false, R.raw.load)
    exerciseList.add(load)
    val spring = ExerciseModel(3,"Spring",false,false, R.raw.spring)
    exerciseList.add(spring)
```

Add this line for animation:-

```
exerciseAnimation.setAnimation(exerciseList[0].animationJson) //0 is your animationfile position
```

Update your xml code:-

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/exerciseAnimation"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_speed="1" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It worked ! Just one issue, only first animation is showing in motion, the next ones are just showing as static images and not moving !! What's wrong pls answer.

Comment: sorry but i doesn't know without showing it , please show code

Comment: The issue is solved by adding the line exerciseAnimation.playAnimation() . Thank you so much for your sol, it helped a lot.